# how remove required field from billing information into checkout

Tags: 8, commerce, entities

I need to add a checkbox to make billing information same as shipping information in drupal 8. 
So i want remove required fields into billing address and set this information programmatically after submit the form.

But is very hard to remove required fields from billing information into checkout panes.
I also hack the Drupal\address\Element\Address.php at line 202 to set the #required attribute to FALSE but when i submit the form, i have always the message "... field is required."

Why the attribute #required => FALSE doesn't work? Why is so hard to modify this field? Why is not there a template for this field?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use hook_form_alter to changing form elements options. This field is required because very often payments modules need this data to prepare correct post variables.

Comment: You can't. Into form alter you have only an array with element #type => commerce_profile_select and not the single fields of address field

Comment: @Fabio you’re probably looking for https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/8.5.x

Comment: I try but the result is the same. i think that i will create custom shipping and billing pane and will save informations programmatically. thanks